# In Ren'py, can I make a text tag that opens a displayable?

Tags: renpy

I'm developing a visual novel in Ren'py that would benefit from an interactive glossary. Ideally, I'd like words in the text box that are included in the glossary to be highlighted, and if the user clicks on one, the glossary would open at the corresponding entry.

I see that a URL text tag is available, so I'm wondering if it would be possible to do something similar to HTML, where an `<a>` tag can call a Javascript function rather than an actual URL.

Failing that, I know it is possible to make custom tags, but I have not been able to find a way to use these to create an action rather than a new style.

Any advice would be most appreciated, even if it's just to say impossible, so that I can let it go and consider other options.